# Переадресовать двумерный массив

Tags: c++, массивы

Недавно нашел интереснейшую задачу. Очень хочу ее решить, но нет никаких идей (кроме как условиями). Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Пользователь вводит один *(неправильный)* индекс *(двумерного)* массива 3x3 (один из этих):
`a[0] a[1] a[2]`
`a[3] a[4] a[5]`
`a[6] a[7] a[8]`
Нужно вывести правильный соответствующий индекс.
`a[0][0] a[0][1] a[0][2]`
`a[1][0] a[1][1] a[1][2]`
`a[2][0] a[2][1] a[2][2]`
*Пример*
Ввод: `a[7]`
Вывод: `a[2][1]`

Comment: Обычное деление с остатком...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первый индекс - `x / 3`.
Второй индекс - `x % 3`.

В общем случае вместо `3` - ширина массива.